# Map or Fold in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to perform the equivalent of the map or fold operations (in the functional programming sense) in Google Spreadsheets. I have a relatively simple expression that I'd like to apply to many columns (the expression is based on values in a single column) and then sum those results. The sum part is easy if I can perform a map operation (fold would be quicker, but map works fine). The real question is: how do I do this mapping?

I'm basically trying to accomplish something like (in pseudocode):

```
map(functionOfColumn, C1:K1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Were the desired function say "raise to the power of 2" then:

```
=ArrayFormula(C1:K1*C1:K1)
```

To aggregate the results:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(C1:K1*C1:K1))
```